# How can I get QuickFix to process messages that come in from a resend request?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I am writing an acceptor application and using a persistent FIX session.  I am trying to write a recovery mode, such that if I go offline or my program restarts, when I reconnect I want to reprocess all the messages sent to me during the day to get back to the current state.

To do this, when I start up I send a resend request for all messages to the server.  They fire me back all the relevant messages, and they are marked possdupflag=Y and possresend=Y.  Before each message, they send a sequence reset for the repeated message they are about to send.

The problem is though, these messages do not seem to be processed by my message cracker. Both fromAdmin and fromApp do not get these messages.  I assume they are being ignored because of the dup flag and/or resend.  So is there a way for me to tell QuickFIX that I *want* to see these messages?

On that note- if anyone has any recommendations on better recovery processes I would be open to them.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you managing your own sessions?  Or does QuickFix does that for you? Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 2):

There's at least a couple of potential problems with this recovery strategy. The first is that it's not very friendly to your trading counterparty. If you only receive a small number of messages during your session then it may not be an issue, but if you receive hundreds of thousands of messages then your counterparty might complain about the massive resends.

The other issue is that message resend is intended for error recovery and is managed by the session protocol layer. In QuickFIX/J (and other FIX engines) the session maintains recovery state in addition to sending the ResendRequest automatically when it detects a sequence number gap. Your approach might work if you reset the next expected incoming sequence number to 1. When the session receives the next message with a higher sequence number it will detect the gap and request the missing messages. If the messages are validated, they will be forwarded to application layer with the PossDup flag set. If you send the ResendRequest message yourself the behavior is undefined since the session state will not have been set up properly.

I recommend using a MessageLog implementation to store your incoming messages in a form you can use for recovery when your application starts. You can look at the implementation of the existing message logs (FileLog, JdbcLog) to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour occurs because the engine's persistance system tells it that the recieved messages are resent messages and so (per the FIX protocol specification) are discarded. Here we save FIXml strings into our database to provide a similar recovery ability to that which you describe(they are also written to xml files on disk for other reasons). I don't believe that there is any way to tell quickfix that you want to see duplicate messages but it is probably better to use a different form or persistance to save on connection overheads. Quickfix does provide a way of outputting messages to file as they come in if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I too have the same issue and What Frank Says is absolutely correct , 
Just use the below method to set the target sequence number to the begin seq number of the desired resend req .

```
 getSession()->setNextTargetMsgSeqNum(atoi(seq.c_str()));
```

The engine internally identifies that the target number is way too large and automatically sends resend request , and all messages will be captured in onMessage call back itself as usual